# How to get more data from a relationship table in Yii

Tags: yii, yii-relations

I have 3 tables:

1. **numbers** (id, name)
2. **food** (id, name)
3. **numbers_food** (number_id, food_id, price_per_ad, price_per_ch)

How I can to get a **price_per_ad** and **price_per_ch** data for each **food_id** from **numbers_food** relationship table?

Comment: Is `numbers_food` just a table or do you have the according model NumbersFood ? (The answer will depend on that)

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/285/accessing-data-in-a-join-table-with-the-related-models/

Answer (score 1):

Just define relationships in models.

In NumberFoodModel:

```
'food'    => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Food',    'food_id'),
```

In FoodModel:

```
'number_food'    => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'NumberFood',    'food_id'),
```

Now in your code just use

```
Food::model()->with('number_food')->findByPk($id)
```